# Energy and electromotive force in transformers

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

I just learnt the formula $ε_2=ε_1\frac{N_2}{N_1}$ in relation to transformers. While I understand the mathematics that were used to derive it, I am having difficulty understanding where the extra electromotive force comes from (assuming that N2 is larger than N1), in light of the laws governing preservation of energy. Could somebody give a qualitative explanation to make it a bit easier to conceptualise?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For an ideal transformer the power in is equal to the power out ie $\mathcal E_1 I_1 =\mathcal E_2 I_2$.

This means that if the output voltage is larger than the input voltage $\mathcal E_2> \mathcal E_1$ then the output current is smaller than the input current $I_2<I_1$.
A voltage "step-up" transformer is also a current "step-down" transformer so you do not get something for nothing in terms of energy.
In general transformer are not $100\%$ efficient and so the output power is less than the input power.

Comment: A very good explanation, thank you!

Just so that I get this absolutely straight:
to me instinctively I and V are positively correlated, so the fact that that you lose V in order to gain in I (or the other way round) seems rather counterintuitive.

Is there any explanation how a larger difference in Voltage between either side of the coil actually translates into a /lower/ current?

Comment: @Pregunto Just the law of conservation of energy.  Is you have a transformer you should find that the windings at the high voltage side are thinner than those at the low voltage side since the current is smaller at the high voltage side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you get more (EMF) force with the with N2>N1 but force is not energy. What happens is if you have 1 amp in the primary you will get say 0.1 amp in the secondary (assuming 10:1) so power is conserved.

As Farcher states some transformers are built N1>N2 and the power is still conserved.

Answer (score 1):

PhysicsDave and Farcher have already pointed out that energy is not  force and that energy into the ideal transformer primary equals energy out, so that energy is conserved. For your equation:

$$ε2=\frac {N_2}{N_1}ε1$$

The reason why $ε2$, which is the voltage induced in coil 2 is greater than $ε1$, the voltage in coil 1, is the changing magnetic flux in coil 2 encloses more winding turns than the changing magnetic flux in coil 1. According Faraday’s Law, 
$$v=-N\frac{dϕ}{dt}$$
where
v = the induced voltage,
ϕ = the average flux (webers) enclosed by each turn, and
N= number of turns in the coil

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Think of a transformer as a gear box in a car. the gear ratios are analogous to the turns ratio in a transformer. For example, a step-down transformer reduces voltage and increases current, like a gearbox that reduces torque and increases RPM.